# How to read n to n + i lines in c++?

Tags: c++, file, ifstream, getline

This is the file to be read

> ```
> 5
> Name1
> Name2
> Name3
> Name4
> Name5
> ```

My current code to read this is:

```cpp
void readData(string fileName, string names[], int n) {
    ifstream myFile("file.txt");
    string line;

    if (myFile.is_open())
    {
        myFile >> n;  // read first line
        cout << n; 

        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            getline(myFile, line);
            names[i] = line;
            cout << names[i] << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

I want to put the names into the array names[], but even though n = 5, it seems like it runs only 4 times. Why is that?

This is my current output that I get:

```cpp
5
Name1
Name2
Name3
Name4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didnt read the whole first line when you did `myFile >> n`. So the first getline just read the rest of that line, which is empty

Do

```
 myFile >> n; 
 getline(myFile, line); // read rest of line
```

or

```
 getline(myFile, line); // read whole line
 n =  stoi(line);   // convert to int
```